# language for simple key-value file (mostly for syntax highlighting)

Tags: programming-languages, syntax-highlighting, github-flavored-markdown

so i have some simple files that contain key-value pairs like this:

```
TITLE       language for simple key-value file (mostly for syntax highlighting)
DESCRIPTION so i have some simple files that contain key-value pairs like this.
DESCRIPTION
DESCRIPTION values can span multiple lines (in which case the key is just
DESCRIPTION repeated)
URL         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72677445
```

so basically this is a declarative DSL for expressing dictionaries: the first word in each line is the key, and the rest is the value; key and value are separated by an arbitrary amount of whitespace.

now, i would like these files to gain some basic syntax-highlighting (so that the "key" part is shown differently from the "value" part), mostly for github/gitlab/...

unfortunately I have no idea which "language" i should use.

- the syntax is so minimal, that autodetection just ends up with "plain text".
- modern syntax highlighters support a plethora of languages (e.g. [linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) lists about 650 different languages), which makes it impractical to try each one.

any ideas how this "language" is called (or which base-language i could abuse for syntax-highlighting)?

Comment: If your text editor is regex based, it's not that hard to define your own.

Comment: parsing is trivial. i want to attach some label to it, so that **existing** syntax highlighters (like linguist) will do a reasonable job. i'm sure there's already some existing language that i could use (and this is what i'm looking for). i'm not sure whether submitting a PR against an existing highlighter is not an overkill (esp. since my assumption is that there's already a definition for my "language")